# HSTS.plist - anyone know what this is about/from?

Tags: macos, safari

HSTS.plist. Anyone know what this file is about? I thought it was a mal file slipped in, but it does seem to come from Apple. I have accounts at none of the sites listed in the file and visited twitter (it's listed in the file) only once recently to see what William Shatner had to say.

It is found in ~/Library/Cookies/HSTS.plist

Delete it, it comes back.

Found in both Mavericks and Yosemite.

Answer (score 2):

HSTS.plist is a Safari settings file related to HTTP Strict Transport Security. It is a mandatory setting for Mavericks and newer OS releases. For more information about this security policy mechanism, you can read up about it at Wikipedia:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security

Comment: Thank you! What's on that list are sites I would never visit, so it looks like something that doesn't belong on my computer. But I should put it back/let it back in. Thanks, that was easier than I thought it would be.

Comment: You absolutely want this to remain on your computer. Leave it alone and let Safari maintain its security. :)